# master db's buffer size very big What is it reason

Tags: sql-server-2008

In Sql Server 2008 R2 Express Edition,master db buffer size very big.Generally other sql servers it is 1 mb.in our system it is 890 mb.it use all buffer size of sql.

Comment: How did you calculated master DB buffer size can you show me please ?

Answer (score 1):

The DMV [sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-buffer-descriptors-transact-sql) will help you break down which tables from the master database (or any database) are being cached in memory.

This query from that Books Online page can be run from the master database and give you a list of which objects are involved:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)AS cached_pages_count   
    ,name ,index_id   
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors AS bd   
    INNER JOIN   
    (  
        SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name   
            ,index_id ,allocation_unit_id  
        FROM sys.allocation_units AS au  
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p   
                ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id   
                    AND (au.type = 1 OR au.type = 3)  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT object_name(object_id) AS name     
            ,index_id, allocation_unit_id  
        FROM sys.allocation_units AS au  
            INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p   
                ON au.container_id = p.partition_id   
                    AND au.type = 2  
    ) AS obj   
        ON bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id  
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()  
GROUP BY name, index_id   
ORDER BY cached_pages_count DESC;
```

It might be that someone accidentally created objects in master, and they're being queried. These results will help you figure out the mystery. Enjoy!

Comment: I did use this  query : 

 ​SELECT
    databases.name AS database_name,
    COUNT(*) * 8 / 1024 AS mb_used
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
INNER JOIN sys.databases
ON databases.database_id = dm_os_buffer_descriptors.database_id
GROUP BY databases.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;​


And ı saw master db used 890mb buufer size. 

We solved the problem server 2012 updated and sql updated later its ok.Now master db buffer size 1 mb.